# reflection woes utilizing generalized lambda with parameter from this pointer

Tags: c++, reflection, lambda, c++14

I have 3 compilers disagreeing on the below C++14 code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename P, typename F>
constexpr auto can_call(P* p, F&& f) -> decltype(f(p),std::true_type{}) { return {}; }

template <typename F>
constexpr std::false_type can_call(void const*, F&&) { return {}; }

struct C {
  C() { auto pc = can_call(this, [&](auto p) -> decltype(p->f(3)) {}); }
  void f(int);
};

template <typename T>
struct CT {
  CT() { auto ptc = can_call(this, [&](auto p) -> decltype(p->f(3)) {}); }
  void f(T);
};

int main()
{
  C oc;
  auto pc = can_call(&oc, [&](auto p) -> decltype(p->f(3)) {});
  CT<int> oct;
  auto ptc = can_call(&oct, [&](auto p) -> decltype(p->f(3)) {});
}
```

clang++ 3.7 accepts it without a hitch.

g++ 4.9, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3 and trunk fail the `CT<T>` constructor, with the message:

```
t.cpp: In instantiation of ‘CT<T>::CT() [with T = int]’:
t.cpp:24:11:   required from here
t.cpp:16:61: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘auto:2’
     CT() { auto ptc = can_call(this, [&](auto p) -> decltype(p->f(3)) {}); }
                                                              ^
```

VisualStudio 2015 Community is the exact opposite of g++ and fails all lambdas, except the templated `CT<T>` constructor, complaining that left of `'->f'` must be a pointer. (I have not checked if perhaps it wrongly gets the `std::false_type` result in the `CT<T>` constructor.)

From this I have two questions:

1. What is expected? I have tried to read the (draft C++17) standard from github, but to be honest I don't even know where to look, especially since the compilers disagrees a bit too much.
2. Can the intended reflection be portably implemented in a different way? I want (not need) the functionality to improve compilation error messages from a library.

Comment: Stop abusing those poor compilers.

Comment: @rollbear Removing explicit return types (`-> decltype(...)` things) make it compile with all three compilers.

Comment: @JameyD there is some merit to that suggestion.

Comment: @Drop yes, but I want to get `std::false_type` if the function cannot be called, and it's the explicit return type that causes the SFINAE selection. Without it you get a compilation error.

Comment: MSVC is still not good at expression SFINAE, and GCC has many issues with lambdas in templates.